# Insert item under specified listItem in unorderdlist instead of at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a comment system for a website which gets comments via Ajax request and them adds them to a list of comments. This works fine however it always adds them to the bottom of the list. This is because i'm using `list.appendChild(item);` for which I now need to find an alternative...

Is there a way to add a `<li>` element under another `<li>` of which I know the id?

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/flVTWkj2_jM) containing current behavior

and the code for that:

```
function loadcomments(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/getcomments/',
        data: {
            'identifier': '{{ identifier }}',
            'id': id,
            'begin': '0',
            'end': '30',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data.comments);
            console.log(json);
            makeUL(json);
            function makeUL(array) {
                list = document.getElementById('commentlist');
                for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if(!document.getElementById("comment-id-" + array[i].pk)){
                        var item = document.createElement('li');
                        item.className = "commentlistelement"
                        item.setAttribute('id',"comment-listitem-id-" + array[i].pk)
                        var maindiv = document.createElement('div')
                        maindiv.setAttribute('id',"comment-id-" + array[i].pk);
                        maindiv.className = "row comment";
                        maindiv.setAttribute("style","padding-left: "+3*array[i].fields.indent+"vw;");
                        maindiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"col-md-1\">profile<br>pic</div><div class=\"col-md-9\"><small>"+ array[i].fields.user +"  </small><small><button class=\"buttonlink\" onclick=\"reply("+ array[i].pk +")\">reply</button></small> <small><button class=\"buttonlink\" onclick=\"loadcomments("+ array[i].pk +")\">show more</button></small><br><p>" + array[i].fields.description + "</p></div>";
                        item.appendChild(maindiv);
                        list.appendChild(item);
                    }
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make use of the `firstChild` and `insertBefore` methods of the Node object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

JQuery also has an insert after method as well:

http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Get the first child of the list container. Then insert before it.

Comment: `insertBefore` sounds promising but that apparently does not exist :(

Comment: Nevermind: https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2009/08/javascript-insertafter/

Comment: It certainly does exist. Look at the links I posted. There is a jquery version too: http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

Since you are using jQuery, there is no need to use the native js api as you will need to be more verbose and won't have the power of jQuery to help manipulate the DOM.

you can simply use `$.fn.after(html)` or `$.fn.append(html)` depending on where you need the comment to sit in the comment.

```js
// mock ajax call that will resolve in under 400ms
$.mockAjax = ({ parent }) => {
  const $promise = $.Deferred()
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    $promise.resolve([
      { id: 11, comment: 'first child comment', parent: 1 },
      { id: 12, comment: 'second child comment', parent: 2 },
      { id: 12, comment: 'second child comment 2', parent: 2 },
      { id: 13, comment: 'click me again', parent: 3 },
      { id: 23, comment: 'third grandchild comment', parent: 13 },
    ].filter(x => x.parent == parent))
  }, Math.random() * 400)
  
  return $promise.promise()
}

// api getter
const getChildComments = parent =>
  $.mockAjax({ parent })

// comments renderer
const renderComments = comments =>
  $('<ul class="comments">')
    .append(comments.map(({ id, parent, comment }) =>
      `<li class="comment" data-comment-id="${id}" data-parent-id="${parent}">
        ${comment}
      </li>`
    ))

// delegate the event
$(document.body).on('click', '.comment', function(e) {
  const $this = $(this)
  // don't allow the event to bubble up through the dom
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  // only get content if not already loaded
  if ($this.data('loaded')) {
    $this.toggleClass('hide')
  } else {
    // set the loading state
    $this.addClass('loading')
    getChildComments($this.data('comment-id'))
      // convert the comments to jQuery objects to be added to the DOM
      .then(renderComments)
      // append the comments to the DOM inside the clicked comment
      .then($comments => $this.append($comments))
      // clean up your comment state
      .then(() => 
        $this
          .removeClass('loading')
          .data('loaded', true)
       )
  }
})
```

```css
.comment {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comment.loading  {
  color: red;
}

.comment.hide > .comments {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="comments" id="comments">
  
  <li class="comment" data-comment-id="1">has single child comment</li>
  <li class="comment" data-comment-id="2">has two child comments comments</li>
  <li class="comment" data-comment-id="3">has grandchild comments</li>
  <li class="comment" data-comment-id="4">no child comments</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Looks cool! Might look into having the mockAjax thingwork for me!

Comment: the mock ajax is just a way to provide data with a similar api to jQuery.ajax, you should replace it with the ajax query to get your comments